# Is there anyway to search and get the value of <a>.. </a>?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, mechanize-ruby

In a webpage suppose i have the below values:

```
<td> <a href="https://www.test.com/test123/a.html"> test11 </a> </td>
<td> <a href="https://www.test.com/test12333/r.html"> test12 </a> </td>
<td> <a href="https://www.test.com/testaa123/t.html"> test21 </a> </td>
<td> <a href="https://www.test.com/test123123/b.html"> test31 </a> </td>
```

Is there anyway to find the value `test21` using Ruby?

Or  is there anyway to find the `href` values which has a substring `/testaa123/t.html`?

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Is there any way you can provide sample code showing what you've written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this [tutorial](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/) for Nokogiri.

Example for a `<li>` tag:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'
PAGE_URL = "http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/files/hello-webpage.html"

page.css('li')[0].text
```

This will output YouTube from the site below:

```
<div id="funstuff">
   <p>Here are some entertaining links:</p>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a data-category="news" href="http://reddit.com">Reddit</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://kathack.com/">Kathack</a></li>
      <li><a data-category="news" href="http://www.nytimes.com">New York Times</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```