# how to get the current URL of a webpage in selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, ruby-1.9.3

I am using selenium webdriver to do some automation on browser. now there is a need to get the current url of the page currently opened in the browser.

***I wrote the below code but giving me error:***

```
element = driver.find_element :name => "btnSearch"
element.click

all_table_data = driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "td")

 all_table_data.each do |td|

   puts td.text

 end

 print driver.get_url
```

***But it is giving me an error:***

```
filedownload.rb:30:in `<main>': undefined method `get_url' for #<Selenium::WebDr
iver::Driver:0x4292df26 browser=:firefox> (NoMethodError)
```

Can anyone help me here to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `driver.current_url` instead of `get_url`.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/zzP5IDgxP5A

Documentation for the Selenium::WebDriver::Driver class:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/2.9.1/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver

Comment: `+1` to you. Could you please look into [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428265/is-there-anyway-to-search-and-get-the-value-of-a-a/14428664#14428664)? This is not answered properly.If you gave any good suggestions,then it would be helpful for me also.